# Select record(s) from mysql table where date is greater than or equal to today

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am working  on a project that has rows in the database that contains a date. I want to echo the data for the fields that have a date that is equal or greater to today. I have looked at other post and tried a lot of different methods and have yet to succedd. Currently what I have returns an error when I do >= but when I just do = with the statement below, I get all rows from the database.

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM drives WHERE ddest = '{$trimmed}' AND 'leave_date' => DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y') LIKE '%$trimmed%' ORDER BY timeago DESC";
```

Comment: What is `LIKE '%$trimmed%'` supposed to do?

Comment: I usually use something like `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE datestored >= \'' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '\';'`

Comment: It returns data where ddest is based on a query, which is trimmed. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM drives WHERE ddest = '{$trimmed}' AND 'leave_date' >= NOW() LIKE '%$trimmed%' ORDER BY timeago DESC";
```

else this,

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM drives WHERE ddest = '{$trimmed}' AND 'leave_date' >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y') LIKE '%$trimmed%' ORDER BY timeago DESC";
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work. Ieave_date is in the form of 01/01/2017, that is why I thought it was good to format CURDATE().

Comment: then try to do this 'leave_date' >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y'). I only corrected your greater than or equal to operator sign

Comment: @FunshoOlaniyi you are right but syntax is wrong lil bit..because mysql default date format is 'Y-m-d' os 'leave_date' >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d')'

Comment: @NileshDaladra, kyle explained that the Ieave_date is in the form of 01/01/2017, that was why I left it that way

Answer (score 1):

**try this query** if you want a date that is equal or greater to today.

```
select * from drives where day(now()) <= day(ddest) and year(ddest) >= year(now());
```

Answer (score 0):

A valid query might look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM drives 
 WHERE ddest = '{$trimmed}' 
   AND leave_date >= CURDATE()
 ORDER 
    BY timeago DESC
```

Any remaining problems are more likely to do with the way you're handling our data rather then with the query itself.